# Pagemap file consumes a lot of space, how to fix it?

Tags: boot, 20.04, disk-usage

The pagemap file got bigger (80 GB) so there is no space remaining for the Ubuntu to work.

I have deleted that file but can't figure out the cause of the problem.

Is there any way I can prevent the generation of those files in future? I'll be careful while doing that.

Comment: Where was the pagemap file generated? Have you found a solution to the problem by now?

Comment: Are you talking about `/proc/[pid]/pagemap`? That's a virtual file that does not reside on disk, and does not take any storage. I think you're referring to something else (maybe a swapfile)? Can you tell us more about this file, e.g. where it was located?

Comment: it was in the system folder I have to boot from a live USB stick delete that file and again repair files of ubuntu after that os worked fine

Comment: Yeah, I took backup of /etc and then I saw in somewhere like that /proc there's a pagemap file which took 280GB and then my storage ran out of space. don't know how much bigger that file could  have been if I didn't ran out of capacity